# How can I create a good subset of data proportional to the full data set

Tags: statistics, data-analysis

I am programming a neural network and I need to use some data to train it.
I am following the steps of an experiment which tried to predict direction of stock price index movement using neural networks.

I now have my own historical data set and I have gathered statistics about price movement as in Table 1 of this [experiment](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/222043783_Predicting_direction_of_stock_price_index_movement_using_artificial_neural_networks_and_support_vector_machines_The_sample_of_the_Istanbul_Stock_Exchange).

However, I do not know how to create a subset of data the same way they did.

> The research data used in this study is the direction of daily closing
>   price movement in the ISE National 100 Index. The entire data set
>   covers the period from January 2, 1997 to December 31, 2007. The total
>   number of cases is 2733 trading days. The number of cases with
>   increasing direction is 1440 while the number of cases with decreasing
>   direction is 1293. That is,
>   52.7% of the all cases have an increasing direction and 47.3% of the all cases have a decreasing direction. [...] The first subset was used to
>   determine efficient parameter values for evaluated ANN and SVM models.
>   This data set is called ‘‘parameter setting data set’’ and used in the
>   preliminary experiments. **The parameter setting data set is consisted
>   of approximately 20% of the entire data set and is proportional to the
>   number of increases and decreases for each year in the entire data
>   set.**

My data looks like this:

[image: Example data]

from 2004 to 2012.

And for instance I have the following stats about its repartition for 2004:

[image: 2004 stats]

I want to create the subset for 2004, so I need to select 20% of the data, which means 52 values with 27 values increasing and 25 values decreasing.

How should I create this subset?

**Should I pick values randomly or should I pick values following each others ?**

Comment: If your neural network will be using data that comes sequentially, you should train it on sequential data.

Comment: Ok thanks. I did as you said and tried to select subset of data with the most sequential data